# BackgroundWorker and ShowDialog()

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, showdialog

I have to create a Loading form, while processing a calculus. This form should prevent any action to the other forms while performing this calculus so the most proper command to use should be ShowDialog(). I've also found that I need to run this command, in order to prevent the form freezing, with a BackgroundWorker. So what I've done is to define the button - that will start the calculus - and the BackgroundWorker itself. So this is what I wrote:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Form18.ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    Form18.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Form18.ShowDialog()
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
[calculus code and progressbar progression]
If Form18.ProgressBar1.Value = Form18.ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
    Form18.Close()
    hrrnativexcel.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Even if I'm using the BackgroundWorker, when I press the button, the loading form - declared in my code as Form18 - becomes blocked and progressbar gets stuck at 0% loading. Could anyone tell me where I am doing wrong? I've tried to find something about BackgroundWorker with ShowDialog command but I haven't found anything that could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must change order as  your app is waiting for `DialogResult` as you have called `.ShowDialog()`.
So, if doesn’t `.Close` your `Form18` `BackgroundWorker1` doesn’t start her job. The other thing to be mentioned is that you doesn’t have any `.ReportProgress` (May be is the [calculus....] ???) in the code you have posted

Comment: The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do background work. Anything to do with the UI is, by definition, NOT background work. You also seem not to know how default instances work. They are thread-specific, so you're referring to two different `Form18` instances in those two event handlers. You should [read this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567).

Comment: OT, the fact that you have a `Button4` is bad enough but a `Form18` is terrible. Those names are completely meaningless and thus all but useless. If you put that code away for a while and come back to it, you'll have no idea what's what. It's happened to all of us so don't think that it won't to you. You should apply a MEANINGFUL name to everything.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj thanks for commenting. This is the first time I'm using BackgroundWorker command so I didn't know anything about DialogResult and ReportProgress. What I reported as [calculus] is an algorythm for exporting data in excel and to fill in the progress bar, anything about what you said to me.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your suggestions. In my future I'll provide more meaningful name for tools, this is my first programming experience and I have a notepad with all the translation of these names. By the way, I'll read the thread you reported me. Thank you so much again.